# C++ accepting positive integers only

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a programming assignment and am having trouble with checking the input placed by the user. The program is where you enter two positive numbers only, however when I enter a character, such as 'a' as my first "number", the program accepts it and outputs it as if I entered a zero. It should output "Invalid number: Numbers must be positive integer." Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

```
//Program where user enters two positive numbers
//and program will display various things.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Displays information of what program will do
cout<< "Practice with iterations\n\n"
    << "The function of this program is, given 2 positive numbers, the"
    << " program";
cout<< "\nwill display the following\n\n";

cout<< "\t1. All even numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
    << "\t2. All odd numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
    << "\t3. Sum of all even numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
    << "\t4. Sum of all odd numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
    << "\t5. All prime numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
    << "\t6. Factorial of the secondNum.\n"
    << "\t7. The numbers and their squares between firstNum and "
    << "secondNum."<< endl;

//Declare first and second number variables
int firstNum;
int secondNum;
bool flag= true;    //Set to true
char x;             //Use to see if value entered is letter

//Ask user to input values
cout<< "\n\nEnter the first number:\t\t";
cin>> firstNum;

if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    flag= 0;
}

cout<< "Enter the second number:\t";
cin>> secondNum;

if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    flag= 0;
}

//If user puts wrong input
if (firstNum>secondNum)
    cout<< "\nError: First number must be < second number.\n";
else if (firstNum<0 || secondNum<0)
    cout<< "\nError: Invalid number: Number must be positive.\n";
else if (firstNum==x || secondNum==x)
    cout<< "\nError: Invalid number: Numbers must be positive integer.\n";
else
{
    cout<< "\nYou entered: "<< firstNum<< " and "<< secondNum;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (firstNum==x || secondNum==x)
    cout<< "\nError: Invalid number: Numbers must be positive integer.\n";
```

this test is wrong x is not initialized and it doesn't really make sense..plus you have used the flag to test the fail input case i assume so your code should be like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Displays information of what program will do
    cout << "Practice with iterations\n\n"
        << "The function of this program is, given 2 positive numbers, the"
        << " program";
    cout << "\nwill display the following\n\n";

    cout << "\t1. All even numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
        << "\t2. All odd numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
        << "\t3. Sum of all even numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
        << "\t4. Sum of all odd numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
        << "\t5. All prime numbers between firstNum and secondNum.\n"
        << "\t6. Factorial of the secondNum.\n"
        << "\t7. The numbers and their squares between firstNum and "
        << "secondNum." << endl;

    //Declare first and second number variables
    int firstNum;
    int secondNum;
    bool flag = true;    //Set to true

                        //Ask user to input values
    cout << "\n\nEnter the first number:\t\t";
    cin >> firstNum;

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        flag = 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter the second number:\t";
    cin >> secondNum;

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "lol" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        flag = 0;
    }

    if (flag) {
        if (firstNum > secondNum)
            cout << "\nError: First number must be < second number.\n";
        else if (firstNum < 0 || secondNum < 0)
            cout << "\nError: Invalid number: Number must be positive.\n";

        else
        {
            cout << "\nYou entered: " << firstNum << " and " << secondNum;
        }
    }
    else cout << "Error input" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error in reading the input, you have the first steps correctly accounted for -- clear the input stream and clear the error state of `cin`. What you are missing is reading something valid into the variable. For that you need a loop.

```
while (true )
{
   //Ask user to input values
   cout<< "\n\nEnter the first number:\t\t";

   // Try to read the input. If it is successful, break out of the loop.
   if ( cin>> firstNum )
   {
      break;
   }

   // Clear the error flag. Clear the input stream. Try again.
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(256,'\n');
}
```

Do the same thing for the second number.